# Is this a false "PossibleMultipleEnumeration"?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have an `IEnumerable` options. I need the `totalCount` (max number of options), but I want to display only 15, let's say.

Is this code bad performance? Re# says `PossibleMultipleNumerations`, but my intuition says it's a false one.

```
IEnumerable<someclass> options = from entry in someList select new SomeClass
{ Id = entry.id,
Value = entry.term
};

var totalOptions = options.Count();
var results = options.skip(10).take(15);
```

Comment: How would it be false? `Count()` will enumerate it, and then you'll start again with `Skip`. Now maybe that's okay, but it's definitely not a false positive to warn about that.

Comment: yep, you are right. But I do need both count all and skip/take - pagination. I believe there's no other way but to Enumerate it twice :)

Comment: Yes there is - but it requires more work. You'd skip the first 10 items, remember the next 15 items, then count (but not retain) the remaining ones.  Note that when counting, you probably don't need to be performing the projection, either... in an ideal world, you wouldn't generate that garbage. (So transform the page you actually get, rather than the source.) If you're not worried about the performance of this code, you can ignore the warning - otherwise, I can write to write some code for you that would be more efficient.

Comment: some code examples would be great, Jon!

Comment: Done. It's a bit ugly, but hey...

Answer (score 3):

You're currently iterating through it once for `Count`, then again for `Skip` and `Take`. While counting, you're also performing the projection pointlessly. Fixing all of that is entirely doable, although pretty ugly. Here's code that should work (although it's entirely untested), and be more efficient, iterating only once.

```cs
// Note: this should be in a static non-generic top-level class.
public static List<TResult> SkipTakeSelectCount<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int skip,
    int take,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
    out int count)
{
    List<TResult> page = new List<TResult>();
    count = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        count++;
        if (skip > 0)
        {
            skip--;
        }
        else if (take > 0)
        {
            take--;
            page.Add(selector(item));
        }
    }
    return page;
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```cs
var results = someList.SkipTakeSelectCount(
    skip: 10, take: 15,
    entry => new SomeClass { Id = entry.Id, Value = entry.Term },
    out int totalOptions);
```